# Iphone OpenGL: Getting position of an object / current identity

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, matrix

due to there not being an easy way to work out if you clicked on an object in a 3d world,  I decided to build my own function to do it which will be very simple

So far, what I am doing is creating a square that's always a little bit in front of me even if I move or rotate.

What I then want to know is that objects position now in 3d space?

I thought that this would give me the new position

```
GLfloat matrix[16]; 
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
```

To stick an object in front of me I am doing the following

```
glTranslatef(eye[0], 1 , eye[2]);
glRotatef(-rotation, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(0, 0 , 10);
```

This works well :)

**The Question is**

How do I get the position of the square that I put in front of me (10 points in front of me).  I want the world x,y,z coordinates

Comment: Have a search for relevant tags [opengl] [picking] on StackOverflow.

Comment: iphone does not support picking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the current world-space coords of a point in screen-space, you can use `gluUnProject` function. This will come in handy for you.

There's also `gluProject` for doing this in reverse order.

Comment: I had a play with this and it seems to do something but god knows what.  Looked at http://softwareprodigy.blogspot.com/2009/08/gluunproject-for-iphone-opengl-es.html